# What offline software or utility can I use to detect minimum Javascript version to run a web application?

Tags: javascript, utility

I have inherited a web application to maintain.  The application entails hundreds of thousands of lines of Javascript across hundreds of libraries that get loaded/unloaded at run time.  I need to add a feature to the site to let a user know if his/her browser doesn't support the minimum Javascript version required to run the site, which, in turn, requires me to analyze all the Javascript in the site in order to know the minimum required version.  The libraries were written/added as-needed over the years, using whatever features Javascript supported at the time, so some libraries can work with older Javascript than others.

**What offline software or utility can I use to analyze all the Javascript in the project and determine the minimum Javascript version that is found?**  By "offline" I mean not uploading the project to a web-based analyzer or otherwise transferring any part of the project to a third party for analyzation.  An open source tool would be preferred, but I would pay for a commercial tool out-of-pocket if absolutely necessary and not more than $100.

Comment: Try softwarerecs for such questions

Comment: This question is off-topic on StackOverflow. It might be appropriate at [SoftwareRecs.SE], but I doubt there is any such tool.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better approach to detect browser failures during runtime?

Comment: Thanks, Marged and Bergi.  I'll post on Software Recommendations.  Marged, that is usually how I would handle it, but this is a very large web application with a lot of different areas, so in this case it would be a nightmare.  Executing every function on the site and logging failures alone (without making any code changes) would take days.

Answer (score 2):

I mean, if you don’t want to use great services provided by browserstack or browserling, then your only three options are:

1. Either use a virtual machine and install every web browser from the first version up
2. Or if you have chrome, you can open up the chrome dev tools and see if it says anything api is deprecated
3. Or you could use w3schools as a reference to which api’s are supported and modify the native api in such a way so that you can see which api’s are being called

Comment: Oh, for the love of God, let's not promote W3 Schools for anything - especially for its compatibility tables.

Comment: Why? It’s so awesome, like just look at w3schools. Every single api with compatibility tables

Comment: [sigh] You will find that it's well-known that W3 Schools often has incomplete, out of date, or just plain wrong information. While they do an excellent job at getting their site to show up at the top of the search results and they have a nice redesigned UI that does appeal to beginners, it's not regarded as a good knowledge base. Instead, look at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org), which is regarded as a definitive source for many different web technologies and languages.

Comment: Interesting, never heard that before, thanks for the info!!!